# Paid Membership Pro with ACF

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, membership

I am using a hook from Paid Membership pro to add ACF fields on a registration form.

```
function insert_acf() {
    echo "<p><div id='content-creator'>Test</div></p>
    <p><?php the_field('organisation_name'); ?></p>";
 };

add_action('pmpro_checkout_before_submit_button','insert_acf');
```

Problem 1: The test div works but it is not displaying the ACF field

Problem 2: How do I associate this ACF field to the newly created subscriber

TIA

Comment: This is probably something you would want to take up with Paid Membership Pro's support.

Comment: Thanks but there is only support on their $297 per year. subscripton I wouldn’t mind spending that if I knew it was going to work, but currently had patchy results with other membership plugins. So I need to see it would work first

Comment: Why has somebody downvoted?

Comment: Can you add the custom fields to the form directly from ACF? Pretty sure the registration-form is one of the conditions available when setting where a custom field appears.

Comment: @NickWild *Why has somebody downvoted?* Possibly to emphasize that [WPSE is not intended as a site to provide support for third-party plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @admcfajn good idea but not specifically for PMP just userforms

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your echo. You are trying to echo a php opening tag. change your function to:

```
function insert_acf() {
    echo "<p><div id='content-creator'>Test</div></p><p>" . get_field('organisation_name') . "</p>";
};
```

This will solve your first problem.

Comment: Thanks but it does not show up

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function insert_acf() {
    $rtfield = "<p><div id='content-creator'>Test</div></p>
    <p>". get_field('organisation_name')."</p>";
    return $rtfield;
 };

add_action('pmpro_checkout_before_submit_button','insert_acf');
```

Now in your dashboard you need to add that field to your user form by going to custom fields, add new field group (or if you already created this field) simply set display if post is user form.

You'll now need to go to a user and add something to the field and save the user changes.

I would also add a conditional to your code in case some of your users don't have the field with data it it yet:

```
function insert_acf() {
  if (get_field('organisation_name')) {
    $rtfield = "<p><div id='content-creator'>Test</div></p>
    <p>". get_field('organisation_name')."</p>";
    return $rtfield;
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks good advice, but this does not even show the test in the div.

Comment: which is "this"?  if you used the 2nd version then it won't because the conditional may not be met.

Comment: I only tried the first one